# SQL error in Ruby on Rails: "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following query in Ruby:

```
mcuglist = Balsiebeltogenevaprodmapping.find_by_sql ["select * from master_cug_list where customer_ref = ? and product_seq = ? and end_date = ? and line_seq is null order by directory_number",bseq_11.customer_ref,bseq_11.product_seq,(accdtlmap.start_dat.to_date + 9).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
```

It is giving me the error given in the title: `(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0`.

Any idea on how to pass `date` to the `find_by_sql query`?

Comment: "who" is giving that error? what kind of column is end_date? if it's a date, likely you should use a string-to-date conversion, e.g. to_date(string, format) or alike...

Comment: Is it just a typo? `accdtlmap.start_dat.to_date`, maybe it should be `accdtlmap.start_date.to_date` (start_date)

Comment: @klump ::No the start_dat is a column name and has been defined as such. @ShinTakezou:: On using to_date it is giving the error 'NoMethodError: undefined method `to_date' '